# How to Insert custom xib cell below the selected row in tableview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, custom-controls, xib

Can any one help me out how to insert custom cell from nib to tableview below the selected row..
Any help would be appreciable... 
Thanks

Comment: If you are a registered developer there was a very nice demonstration of this in a session on table views at WWDC 2011 (or, possibly, might have been 2010). The video is available online free to all registered developers.

Comment: There are a lot of questions in your one question: 1. How to create custom cell. 2. How to detect selected row. 3. How to add new cell to table view. Moreover all that question were answered a lot of times

Comment: WWDC 2011 Session 125 — UITableView Changes, Tips, Tricks

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2011/125/